# "Could not find a 'Notifications' widget which is required for displaying notifications"

Tags: kde, notification

Hello I am running Linux with KDE Plasma and Latte Dock. I have no notifications whatsoever but have a full stack engineering job I start on Monday. Gonna need notifications!

I've looked around a lot but there is no answer to how to fix this. There's a lot of jargon like widgets and what not. I don't really know what that means but it says it under Notifications -- System Settings

Comment: 5.8.0-53-generic Kubuntu 20.10

Comment: The widget is named `System Tray`, make use of the searchbox when trying to add a widget.

Comment: WOW, so if you don't have a system tray you can't have notifications? In all of Linux they don't have a widget that goes out of a tray. You see I run Latte Dock and Plasma so I don't have a system tray. is there a work around for this without adding one? I managed to get dunst notification daemon working but I still don't have other things like the UI notification for volume and such.